# How to track socket connection to one user acrosss multiple pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am a newbie to socket.io. What works so far is that I could use the code below to get the socket on the client connected to the server.

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io();
</script>
```

My question is: how do I enable the connections from different html pages for one user to be identified with that one user? As it is now, the connection is disconnected every time a user changes a page and I would like all the pages/socket objects openned by a user to be linked to that particular user.

Comment: You could use a cookie, and write the user identification to it.

Comment: The strategy will differ based on : if you have a single page application or a simple html application. what are you looking for ?

Comment: I am open to both, but would prefer a simple html application for now.